# The identity 'iPhone Developer' doesn't match any valid, non-expired certificate/private key pair

Tags: xcode, xcode4.5, code-signing

It never happened to me before, I already downloaded sample code before, but now im getting this error:

[image]

I saw some questions with this error, but they say to check your "code signing" and I dont see what is wrong there...

[image]

Please help, im freaking out

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of the drop-down menu you see for "Code Signing Identity"

Comment: did you enter the Bundle Identifier in the plist?

Comment: I'm having the same problems. Tried to read all the answers for this problems. They are talking about getting the certificate, but not sure how to get it and from where. Did you fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

The error means provisioning profile doesn't exist  So

1. Check the Bundle Identifier in the plist file .
2. Go to Codesign Identity and click on the dropdown menu and click on the matching Provisioning Profile ( Matching provisioning profile appears in Black color )

Answer (score 1):

Since the problem deals with code signing, you just have to uncheck the "Code Sign Application" box on Summary Properties. It worked fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

I am suffering the same problem. Most of the answers saying things like Bundle Identifier, provisioning profile, or crap like that.

If people know what those are, they won't come to internet, OK?

check this

http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/Testing_Apps_on_the_iPhone_–_Developer_Certificates_and_Provisioning_Profiles

it explains everything.

Answer (score 0):

Possible fix (that worked for me) :
I changed the scheme "iOS Device" to "iPad 6.1 Simulator" or "iPhone 6.1 Simulator" then I rebuilt the project without this error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error and I found this: [How to make an IPA on XCode 4.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18248363/how-to-make-an-ipa-on-xcode-4-6)

These steps work for me:
1.    Go to /Applications.

2. Right click on XCode and select 'Show Package Contents'.
3. CopyContents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/SDKSettings.plist to your desktop. (Make sure to actually copy and paste. No drag and drop)
4. Open it and under DefaultProperties set CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED to NO.
5. Copy it back and replace the original file.
6. Restart XCode.
7. Open your project.
8. In Project Navigator select your project and open Build Settings section of your porject (and not any particular target)
9. Under Code Signing find Code Signing Identity and for both Debug and Release modes setAny iOS SKD to Don't Code Sign.
10. Now you should be able to build your project without any errors.