# How to make an IPA on XCode 4.6?

Tags: ios6, xcode4.6

I have MAC OS Lion environment and Xcode 4.6.I do not have a Developer's Account.  I want to generate a .ipa file for a sample project so that i could test it on a device.
 1 . Is it even possible?

I saw a similar question answered..and so i tried the following steps accordingly but i am facing a problem with step no 2 below in (to make an IPA).

**To Disable Code Signing:**

1. Go to /Applications.
2. Right click on XCode and select 'Show Package Contents'.
3. Copy Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS5.1.sdk/SDKSettings.plist to your desktop. (Make sure to actually copy and paste. No drag and drop)
4. Open it and under DefaultProperties set CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED to NO.
5. Copy it back and replace the original file.
6. Restart XCode.
7. Open your project.
8. In Project Navigator select your project and open Build Settings section of your porject (and not any particular target)
9. Under Code Signing find Code Signing Identity and for both Debug and Release modes set Any iOS SKD to Don't Code Sign.
10. Now you should be able to build your project without any errors.

**To make an IPA:**

1. In 'Project Navigator' select Products.
2. Right click on [NameOfYourProject].app and select 'Show in Finder'.// This doesn't work .I cannot select the option show in finder.
3. Create a folder and name it Payload
4. Move [NameOfYourProject].app to Payload.
5. Compress Payload and rename it to [NameOfYourProject].ipa

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a hack to get this to work. You need to have a developer account to build and test on a device. However in "To make an IPA" at step 1 have you built your project?

Comment: In Xcode click File > Project Settings. Under Build you will see a file path for Derived Data click on that arrow, it will take you to where all your builds are. You should be able to find the file there providing it did in fact build.

Comment: Look in those files. Try Build/Products/Debug-iphonesimulator and then follow what you posted. When you look for the file it most likely won't have the .app extension at the end. It will just be [NameOfYourProject]

Comment: Okay thank you .Just one last thing though....After step 5,when i have the compressed .ipa ..... should i directly install it in my phone? .. Any idea?

Comment: Yes you will have to do that, I think you will have to do it through iTunes.